# Nuxt : How to use pm2 watch on nuxt-built-app directly?

Tags: nuxt.js, pm2

I commanded `pm2 start --only UI0 --watch`, then pm2 watching would work.

But when I run `npm run build`(nuxt build), it didn't show the changes on the pm2 log, and neither on nuxt app pages.

After then, when I commanded `pm2 restart all` then the nuxt app pages showed the changes.

Could u please let me know how to use pm2 watch on nuxt-built-app directly?

`ecosystem.config.js`

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'UI1',
    exec_mode: 'cluster',
    instances: 0,
    script: path.join(__dirname, '../app_build/node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js'),
    args: 'start',
    //watch: '.',
    env:{
      HOST: '0.0.0.0',
    },
    cwd: path.join(__dirname, '../app_build'),  
  },
  {
    name: 'UI0',
    //exec_mode: 'cluster',
    //instances: 3,
    script: path.join(__dirname, '../app_build/node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js'),
    args: 'start',
    //watch: '.',
    env:{  
      HOST: '0.0.0.0',
    },
    cwd: path.join(__dirname, '../app_build'),
  }],  
};
```